# Regular morphisms and formal power series

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, schemes

Let $A$ be a local noetherian ring. When (besides when $A$ is excellent) do we have that $\operatorname{Spec}(A[[t]])\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A[t])$ is regular?

Answer (score 9):

As you probably are aware, a sufficient condition is that $A$ is a $G$-ring [[Matsumura](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=575344), Thm. 79]. On the other hand, the following result says that one must put some strong assumptions on $A$ to have $A[t] \to A[[t]]$ be regular.

**Theorem** [[Sharp](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/28.4.487), Thm. 2.9]**.** *There exist a local domain $B$ of dimension either two or three such that setting $L = \operatorname{Frac}(B)$, the generic fiber $B[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]] \otimes_B L$ of the homomorphism $B \to B[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$ is not Cohen–Macaulay for every integer $n > 0$.*

The example is based on Ferrand and Raynaud's construction of a local domain $A$ such that the zero ideal in the completion $\hat{A}$ has an embedded prime [[Ferrand–Raynaud](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1195), Prop. 3.3]. This ring $A$ therefore has non-Cohen–Macaulay formal fibers. Sharp's construction also gives a ring $B$ that also has non-Cohen–Macaulay formal fibers by [[Ooishi](https://doi.org/10.32917/hmj/1206134466), Cor. 36].

We can now consider the composition
$$B \longrightarrow B[t] \longrightarrow B[[t]],$$
where $B$ is as in Sharp's theorem. The first map is a regular homomorphism. If the second map were also regular, then the composition would be regular. But Sharp's theorem says that this cannot be the case.